# Does anyone know where I can get a copy of R. P. Steiner, "A theorem on the Syracuse problem"?

Tags: collatz-conjecture

R.P. Steiner. "A theorem on the Syracuse problem". In: ed. by D. McCarthy and H. C. Williams. Congressus numerantium; 20. Proceedings of the 7th Manitoba Conference on Numerical Mathematics and Computation, September 29-October 1, 1977.  Winnipeg: Utilitas Mathematica Pub., 1978, pp. 553-559.

Answer (score 3):

I think there is no open exemplar on the net (I've searched a couple of times intensely).

But the articles of John Simons/Benne de Weger (linked to by wikipedia) from 2000 to 2002 on the $2$-cycle and the $m$-cycle problem refer to it fairly explicite.
Moreover, I've a personal mail of R. Steiner where he sketched his proof-idea for me and it is pretty short: the key seems to be the idea of introducing this Baker-style argument at all. And then the sharpening of bounds by a later author (Mignotte?) which in connection with the continued-fraction-convergents allowed to complete the proof via accessible range of numbers.

Comment: I presume the "sketch" you talk of is only a sketch of a proof of something weaker than the conjecture itself, is it?

Comment: @user334732: It is a sketch (an informal mail) of the essentials of his proof, that there cannot exist any "1-cycle" except the trivial one. For definition what a "1-cycle" is, please read wikipedia or some of my recent answers to recent collatz-tagged-questions here.

Comment: Thanks. I believe a 1-cycle goes up then down, withonly one change of direction, when seen using the $\{(3x+1)/2,x/2)$ version of the problem. Which I once before misinterpreted for just goes up then down in the $\{3x+1,x/2\}$ version - which is of course trivial to prove.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want,
but a Google search for
"R.P. Steiner. "A theorem on the Syracuse problem"."
returned this as the first link:

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X06001223

The paper is freely downloadable.

Comment: The Steiner paper is just a reference in the linked paper.

Comment: Right.  This paper only references the Steiner paper.  I actually already have this paper.

Comment: @MathAllTheTime: were you able to send me a copy of the Steiner-article?

Comment: @GottfriedHelms I just e-mailed it to you.  Let me know if you do not receive.  It is 7 separate emails, one for each page.

Comment: @MathAllTheTime : ah, thank you. Got it... very nice!

Comment: @GottfriedHelms: You are certainly welcome!

Comment: I am a graduate student at University of Bonn and I also would like to read the paper, can somebody mail it to me?

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Is there any chance you still have the Steiner paper and could send it to me? I need it for a school project. I would ask MathAllTheTime, but it seems he hasn't been online in over two years. Thanks.